# SVN (server - pre-commit hook): Know the list of files that are being committed

Tags: svn

I would like to know how to get the list of files that are being committed on the pre-commit hook.

If that list doesn't contain a specific file in a specific path, then I want to reject the commit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `svnlook` in a pre-commit. 
`svnlook changed` gives the changed paths of the commit. Compare this against your list. And reject it if path is found/not found. One simple example for pre-commit could be.

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
SPATH="specific/path"
FOUND=$(svnlook changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | tr -d '\n' | grep -E ".*$SPATH.*")

if [ "$FOUND" != "" ]
then
    echo "Reject commit!" 1>&2 && exit 1
else 
    exit 0
fi
```

Here I removed newlines and grep for the interested path. If path is not found, recject the commit `exit 1`. User will see what you echo there.

Comment: What is the similar of (svn list  repo_path) in the precommit hook?

Comment: I would try `svnlook tree REPOS_PATH` to get everything from that path. Use option `-h` to get some more options.

Comment: could you help me with this topic  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396777/how-to-list-a-specific-directories-in-the-svn-pre-commit-hook

Answer (score 15):

The hook scripts should use the `svnlook` command and not `svn`. The `svnlook` command can take the *transaction number* of the commit (if this is a pre-commit hook, you need to use the transaction number. If this is a post-commit hook, you need the revision number).

Do a `svnlook -h` to see all of the subcommands. Here's a list of them:

- `author` - Retrieve the user ID of the committer
- `cat` - Prints out a file specified
- `changed` - Prints out the files and directories changed
- `date` - Prints out the timestamp of the commit
- `diff` - Prints out the diff of all the files
- `dirs-changed` - Prints out the directories changed (
- `filesize` - Prints out the filesize in bytes`
- `history` - Prints out the *history* (more like `svn log`)
- `info` - Prints out the information of a file
- `lock` - Prints out the lock information
- `propget` - Gets a particular property.
- `proplist` - Lists all properties.
- `tree` - Prints out the directory structure
- `uuid` - Prints out the UUID of the repository
- `youngest` - Prints out the last revision number.

Looks like `svnlook changed` is what you want.

***Two very important things about `svnlook`***:

1. The `svnlook` command cannot change any data, just display it. Some people look to see how you can change a property value with `svnlook`. Answer, you can't.
2. The `svnlook` takes the *Repository Directory Location* as an argument, and not the URL of the repository. This means `svnlook` can only run on the server itself.

Comment: could you please take a look in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236308/how-to-print-arguments-in-svn-hook

Comment: The answer has been given. A SVN Hook only will display what is printed to `STDERR` and not `STDOUT`. And, that will only happen if the hook _fails_ (i.e exits with a non-zero exit value).

Comment: OK, so I have this command in my post-commit hook:
$msg = `$svnlook changed -t "$rev" "$repos"`;
and msg has length of 0, which means command can't execute, this is on windows, so is this command correct at all, because I dont see errors anywhere?

Comment: If it's a **post-commit** hook, use `-r` rather than `-t`.