# How to print arguments in SVN hook

Tags: perl, svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit-hook

I am using windows7 and VisualSVN Server.
I have wrote simple SVN post-commit hook which looks like

```
C:\Perl64\bin\perl C:\repositories\secret-project\hooks\myhook.pl %1 %2
```

and myhook.pl script looks like

```
$svnlook = '"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe"';

$repos = $ARGV[0];
$txn = $ARGV[1];

$msg = `$svnlook changed -t "$txn" "$repos"`;
chomp($msg);

print STDOUT $repos . " " . $txn;
print STDOUT $msg;

exit(0);
```

so basically I just want for now to print changed files. 
Commit goes through with no errors, but I am not seeing anything printed when I go through TortoiseSVN or when I commit through cmd. 
So is it printed at all and if so where is it? 
I also tried to write it in txt file but with no success, what am I missing here? :(

EDIT:

per ikegami's comment, yes the code is running.

I also wrote other sample of script, where I am trying to write something in txt file and send data to small test service I created.

```
$svnlook = '"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe"';

$repos = $ARGV[0];
$txn = $ARGV[1];

#--------------------------------------------
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $server_endpoint = "http://localhost:1337/test";

$msg = `$svnlook changed -t "$txn" "$repos"`;
chomp($msg);
open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt');
print $fh $msg;
close $fh;
print STDOUT "done\n";

# set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');

# add POST data to HTTP request body
my $post_data = '{"$txn":"' . $txn .'"}';
print STDOUT $post_data;
$req->content($post_data);

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print STDOUT "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print STDERR "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print STDERR "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}

exit(0);
```

Now I am sending `$txn` to service I made and I can print it, but when I try to send `$repos` I get error on my service, `Syntax error: unexpected token R`

How does `$repos` look like? Maybe I need to parse it somehow before printing or sending to my service?

EDIT 2:

```
$svnlook = '"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe"';

$repos = $ARGV[0];
$txn = $ARGV[1];

print STDOUT "repos:" . $repos . "rev:" . $txn;

#--------------------------------------------
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $server_endpoint = "http://localhost:1337/test";

$msg = `$svnlook changed -t "$txn" "$repos"`;
chomp($msg);
chomp($reply);

if (length($repos) == 0)
{
print STDERR "my error, repos = 0";
exit(1);
}

if ( length($msg) == 0 )
{
print STDERR "my error, msg = 0";
exit(1);
}

open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt');
print $fh $msg;
close $fh;
print STDOUT "done\n";

# set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');

# add POST data to HTTP request body
my $post_data = '{"$txn":"' . $txn .'"}';
print $post_data;
$req->content($post_data);

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print ST "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}

exit(0);
```

So I added printing of arguments at the begining, checking if length of `$repos` equals 0 and if `$msg` equals 0

and in console I only get

```
svnlook: E160007: No such transaction '85'
my error, msg = 0
```

It is an post-commit hook

Comment: Re "I also tried to write it in txt file but with no success", Was the file created? What I mean is, was your code run at all?

Comment: If your exit code is non-zero, the commit is rejected and whatever you printed to STDERR is sent to the client. Not a good idea to run on a production server, but could be handy if you're just practicing/testing.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion displays to user hook output only if post-commit hook returns non-zero result.

Try to replace `exit(0);` with `exit(1);`

Also `post-commit` hook accepts `revision number` not `transaction name` since transaction is already committed at this point. Are you sure that you setting `post-commit` hook and not `pre-commit`?

Comment: I have tried with exit(1) and I get an error that commit failed because of hook.
what difference there is between hooks for pre-commit and post-commit except the name of argument?

Comment: `pre-commit` hook is executed **before** transaction is committed and usually used for validating content. The `post-commit` hook executed **after** transaction committed and usually used for commit notification, updating website etc. More information about Subversion hooks:   http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.html

Comment: yes, I do understand that, but I am still unable to print actual arguments on console, or print the output of my commands etc. nor I'm able to send them over http or write them in txt file ... could it be some windows issue, should I try to make it on unix based os?

Comment: @DarkoRodic Which hook do you test: pre-commit or post-commit? Stderr output of post-commit hook marshalled to client only if it returns non-zero error code.

Comment: I have added new edit in my question. oh yes, thank you for trying man, I am really confused with this

Comment: @DarkoRodic Just replace `-t` option with `-r` when invoking svnlook.

Answer (score 0):

If you use STDERR instead of STDOUT it outputs:

```
$ svn commit tull -m "testdir"
Adding         tull
svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Debug: repos:'C:\Repositories\BuyPass-LRA' transaction:'7173-5jh'
```