# How to list a specific directories in the SVN pre-commit Hook

Tags: python, svn, visualsvn-server, pre-commit-hook

I want to list specific directories in the SVN pre-commit Hook

when I use `svn list [repor_path]` command 
I got this result :

```
svn list  http://SB-LAP163W/svn/TEST/RC | findstr  13.10
13.10.1/
13.10.2/
13.10.3/
```

that's what I'm looking but when I use the same command doesn't work in the pre-commit hook how can I deal with it using `svnlook` command?

I tried   `SVNLOOK dirs-changed -t TXN-NAME REPOS-PATH` it will give me the changed path `PC/13.10/main/dto/` and in my case, I want to list the folders under `RC` repo not `PC`

PS: RC and PC two directories has the same root

- svn/ILS/RC/
- svn/ILS/PC/

Answer (score 1):

If your path you want to list does not correspond with the changed directory but is fixed then just try

```
svnlook tree svn/ILS/PC | grep -E '13\.10.*/'
```

You will get all folders fulfilling the regexp.

If there are some dependencies to changed files/folders or the commit message use a script as in [SVN (server - pre-commit hook): Know the list of files that are being committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790484/svn-server-pre-commit-hook-know-the-list-of-files-that-are-being-committed/17791562#17791562)